# Debugger Broken (Cannot open fileops.c)

Tags: codeblocks

I'm a C++ newbie (up to 2.4a on www.learncpp.com) and I'm having trouble debugging in codeblocks. The terminal that opens up when I start debugging says "warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
" and whenever I try to do something, an error appears in the bottom right saying that it couldn't open some file called fileops.c

Here's an image:

[image: http://i67.tinypic.com/ay0h00.png]

Answer (score 1):

GDB is [the GNU Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Rest assured,
GDB is not broken.

The pesky `warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted`
has appeared forever in Code::Blocks when you start debugging, due to the way
in which C::B invokes GDB. It is harmless and you can ignore it.

The GDB message `fileops.c: No such file or directory` appears because
you trying to step into a function that is defined in `fileops.c`, which
is a source file of the GNU C Library. You cannot step into such functions
because the source code of the GNU C Library that is linked with
your program is not available to GDB.

In general, the source code of any system library that your program is
linked with will not be available to the debugger and similar messages will
appear if you try to step into functions defined in those libraries.

You have to step *over* those functions and almost always you can do so with a good
will, because the bugs you are looking for are not there. They are in *your* source
code, which *is* available to the debugger, and plodding down through all
of the library calls, even if you could, would likely keep you debugging into
old age.

In short, there is nothing the matter. Just step over the functions that you
didn't write.

Comment: There's an issue with the warning, though. When the program finishes executing, the window closes immediately, therefore it is impossible to see the output. In my settings I have the option checked for pausing the terminal after the program finishes running.